# What is the relationship between an arbitrary angle and its projected value in ordinate?

Tags: trigonometry

To make things clear, I am talking about the value that tends to infinity when the angle nears pi/2. In other words : how much the opposite side of a right triangle will lengthen when we widen its opposite angle (unconstrained to the unit circle).

[Here is a mockup (yes I did invert those x and y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS5Pf.png)

Comment: Have a look at following:https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=To%20improve%20your%20chances%20of%20getting%20an%20answer%2C,to%20others.%205%20Keep%20an%20open%20mind.%20

Comment: According to SOHCAHTOA, the height is $\tan\theta$ times the base. Are you asking how much this increases under $\theta\mapsto\theta+\delta\theta$ for $\delta\theta$ small? If so, do you know enough calculus to differentiate $\tan\theta$ (or at least know what that means & why it's relevant here)?

Comment: The relationship is $x=y_0\tan\theta$, where $y_0$ is the distance of this vertical line to your "vertical" $x$-axis.